# Unity: Сохранение файла на памяти устройства

Tags: unity3d, кодировка, storage

У меня есть RawImage под названием Layer и я хочу при нажатии на кнопку сохранить его в

> storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Program/Image.png

Вот часть кода -

```
public void Download()
{
    byte[] bytes = Layer.EncodeToPNG();

    string Path = "";
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path, bytes);
}
```

Как написать путь сохранения, в интернете я так и не нашёл.
**Каким должен быть путь сохранения и как я могу запрашивать доступ в хранилище у пользователя?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь получается примерно вот так:

```
static string DataFilePath
        {
            get
            {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
                try
                {
                    var contextWrapper = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/content/ContextWrapper");
                    var contextWrapperGetFilesDir = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(contextWrapper, "getFilesDir", "()Ljava/io/File;");

                    using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
                    {
                        using (var unityPlayerCurrentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                        {
                            var unityPlayerCurrentActivityRawObject = unityPlayerCurrentActivity.GetRawObject();
                            var filesDir = AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(unityPlayerCurrentActivityRawObject, contextWrapperGetFilesDir, new jvalue[0]);

                            var file = AndroidJNI.FindClass("java/io/File");
                            var fileGetAbsolutePath = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(file, "getAbsolutePath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
                            var absolutePath = AndroidJNI.CallStringMethod(filesDir, fileGetAbsolutePath, new jvalue[0]);

                            return absolutePath;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log(e.ToString());
                    return Application.persistentDataPath;
                }
#else
                return Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
            }
        }
```

Ваш метод будет выглядеть, примерно, так:

```
public void Download(string fileName)
{
    byte[] bytes = Layer.EncodeToPNG();

    string Path = $"{DataFilePath}/{fileName}";
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path, bytes);
}
```

Comment: Я поблагодарил всем что мог. Вы мне очень помогли т. к. этот вопрос я уже задавал в английской версии два раза и не получил ответа.

Comment: @AltF4, Ну, я рад, что смог помочь - для того тут и сижу)

Comment: Прошу прошения тут проблема такая. Ваш код сохраняет файл там где Application.persistentDataPath даже если я запустил его на андроид. Как можно сохранить прям вот тут - storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Program/Image.png.